# JQuery .show() doesn't work when call another function

Tags: jquery, show, fadeout

I have the simple code below:

```
$("#mensagem").html("Success.");
$("#mensagemRetorno").show();
$("#mensagemRetorno").delay(3000).fadeOut(800);
```

I would like to call the function 'buscaPosto()' after the fadeOut.

```
$("#mensagem").html("Success.");
$("#mensagemRetorno").show();
$("#mensagemRetorno").delay(3000).fadeOut(800, buscaPosto());
```

When I do, the message doesn't appear any more.

Why?

Comment: try $("#mensagemRetorno").delay(3000).fadeOut(800, buscaPosto);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$("#mensagemRetorno").delay(3000).fadeOut(800, buscaPosto());
```

to

```
//                                           removed ()-v
$("#mensagemRetorno").delay(3000).fadeOut(800, buscaPosto);
```

The last arg is the callback function but you were calling the function from there. Note using `()` will call the function.

That is one part of the issue, but in OP you had mentioned,

*When I do, the message doesn't apper any more.*

Are you trying to see the message or hide the message? because `.fadeOut` is to hide the message unless you show it again inside the function `buscaPosto`.

Comment: I wanna see the msg and after 3 secs this will disapper and call de function

Comment: @user2417867 Did you try this answer?

Comment: @user2417867 Don't forget to mark it as upvote/accepted(green tick on top left on the answer) if it worked for you..

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use it short.

```
$("#mensagem").html("Success.");
$("#mensagemRetorno").show().delay(3000).fadeOut(800, buscaPosto);
```